# Email Validation code for python not giving expected output

Tags: python, regex

For email validation, i have following conditions:
1. username should be alphanumeric only(a-z,0-9,A-Z)
2. website name should be a-z
3. extension should be a-z

i am writing a python code as :

```
import re 
def check(email):
    #complete the function
    #the function should return the strings "invalid" or "valid" based on the email ID entered
    if(re.search('^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$@^[a-z]+$.^[a-z]+$',email)):  
        return("valid")  

    else:  
        return("invalid") 


email=input()
print(check(email))
```

---

My input: vk@google.com
But it returns me "Invalid"
It should return as "Valid". What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Your initial pattern will work with:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/fUmD17wB5BHs-j2n)

---

You had: ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+<strike>$</strike>@<strike>^</strike>[a-z]+<strike>$.^</strike>[a-z]+$, where you had:

- End string ancor `$` midstring *2
- Start string ancor `^` midstring *2
- Unescaped `.` which would match any character. Escape with backslash > `\.`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

The above shows why you yield zero matches.

---

To have control over the amount of alpha characters between @ and the dot you could use:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-z]{5,8}\.[a-z]+$
```

Comment: Thanks JvdV. Couple of doubts...Why are we not using \ for unescaping @ ? Why it it only used for .  Because '@' is also being used as a literal character here.                            And second, what if we want to set a limit to number of characters to be used between @ and . say 5-8 characters only between @ and .

Comment: @Vandit. That is because the dot has a special meaning in RegEx and represents and character but newline. The @ has no special meaning. So only characters with special meaning need to be escaped with a backslash to match it literally. And to limit the amount you can say `{5,8}` meaning minimum of 5 and max of 8. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Vandit. Has this been helpfull and answered your question? If so, consider to click on the checkmark next to the answer to accept the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't expect the beginning of the line anywhere in the middle of the line.

```
                     This is not right
              |         |
'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$@^[a-z]+$.^[a-z]+$'
                |        |
                       This is the problem
```

Also, the dot is not escaped, causing the expression to match any character. If you want it to match a literal dot, then you have to proceed it with a slash. Change that to

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+$'
```

Comment: There are more problematic ancors + an unescaped dot. =). Basically what I wrote down in my answer.